ConverterNotFoundException When using GCP Secret manager with Okta
Currently running into an issue while trying to use GCP secret manager to hide okta-client-id and okta-client-secret within application.properties. This issue happens specifically when using secret manager with okta environment variables i.e okta.client.id=${sm://okta-client-id}. The stack trace can be found below. For more details, I am using spring boot (3.3.4), com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:3.0.7, and com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:5.7.0. You can also find the build.gradle below. NOTE This issue only occurs when using secret manager with okta environment properties, if I set a value from secret manager to any non okta property then there is no issue i.e test=${sm://okta-client-secret} works, and also using value annotation works i.e @Value(${sm://okta-client-secret}).
Stack Trace
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString] to type [java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:294)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:185)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:165)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.convertValueIfNecessary(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:265)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:71)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:153)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552)
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.env.OktaOAuth2PropertiesMappingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(OktaOAuth2PropertiesMappingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at com.ga_residential.ga_residential_backend.GaResidentialBackendApplicationKt.main(GaResidentialBackendApplication.kt:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)

Process finished with exit code 0

build.gradle
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.25"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.25"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.25"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}

group = "com.demo-oauth"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:3.0.7")
    implementation("io.github.wimdeblauwe:htmx-spring-boot-thymeleaf:3.5.0")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager:5.7.0")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs.addAll("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


application.properties
spring.application.name=oauth-demo-backend
spring.config.import=sm://
okta.oauth2.issuer=${sm://okta-oauth-issuer}
okta.oauth2.client-id=${sm://okta-client-id}
okta.oauth2.client-secret=${sm://okta-client-secret}

I've tried the suggestions to register a custom converter from this stack overflow thread here, and also tried the suggestions from this github issue here, but none of the solutions work for me. Please NOTE my question is not a repeat of those since my problem does not involve openfeign/feignclient, though the error message is the same, my case is a little different since application properties are loaded before the beans are initialized. Any help is appreciated.
